# How to use multiple values with like in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 select * from user_table where name in ('123%','test%','dummy%')
```

How to ensure that this `where` clause is not an exact match, but a `like` condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not lose indexed access to rows in Oracle a table collection expression can be used:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_table
    JOIN (SELECT column_value filter 
          FROM table(sys.odcivarchar2list('dummy%', '123%', 'test%'))
    ) ON user_table.name LIKE filter
```

The filter expressions must be distinct otherwise you get the same rows from `user_table` multiple times.

Comment: how to include a table output instead of hardcoding the value in odcivarchar2list

Answer (score 9):

In Oracle you can use [`regexp_like`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) as follows:

```
select *
from   user_table
where  regexp_like (name, '^(123|test|dummy)')
```

The caret (`^`) requires that the match is at the start of *name*, and the pipe `|` acts as an OR.

Be careful though, because with regular expressions you almost certainly lose the benefit of an index that might exist on *name*.

Answer (score 5):

Use like this,

```
select * 
from user_table 
where name LIKE '123%' 
OR name LIKE 'test%' 
OR name Like 'dummy%';
```

another option in MySQL

```
select * from user_table where name REGEXP '^123|^test|^dummy';
```